# Counting the number of lines in a file

Tags: java

I am trying to develop a program in java that will count the number of files in a given folder along with the lines of code in each individual file. I currently have code that will only pick up a single file from the folder and count the lines of code for that particular file. Please help me understand how to proceed from here.

My current code:

```
public class FileCountLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File file = new File("E:/WalgreensRewardsPosLogSupport.java"); 
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);    
        int count = 0;               
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) { 
            String line = scanner.nextLine();   
        count++;              
        }           
        System.out.println("Lines in the file: " + count);

    }

}
```

Comment: So, you want for each file of the folder its number of lines, right?

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
String dir ="/home/directory";
File[] dirContents = dir.listFiles();
```

List out each files and apply your code on each of them. Store the filename and line count in a Map.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of @Akhil, implemented:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

File directory = new File("E:/");
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
for (File file : files) {
    if (file.isFile()) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader(file));
        int lineCount = 0;
        try {
            for (lineCount = 0; scanner.nextLine() != null; lineCount++);
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            result.put(file.getName(), lineCount);
        }

    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```